# Limit programs that can connect to the internet on OS X

Tags: macos

I got a 3G modem and a sim card. I have a 100MB day limit and although I mostly use firefox and thunderbird and I take care, sometimes it seems that something is using bandwidth but i do not know exactly what program.

How could i tell OS X that only firefox and thunderbird can connect to the internet? so I avoid checking if the rest of the applications connect to the inrenet

Comment: do you mean that it cat not be implemented using shell programming or apple script?

Comment: Dupe of http://superuser.com/questions/87378/limit-programs-that-can-connect-to-the-internet-on-os-x

Answer (score 2):

OS X has an [IPFW firewall](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/ipfw.8.html), so you might be able to configure this to your needs.

A more user friendly solution would be [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html), which has a free version (prompts every three hours) if you don't want to buy it.

Answer (score 2):

[Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html) can do it.

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of processes that have open connections, you can use:

```
sudo lsof | grep -i tcp | grep ESTABLISHED
```